# Using multiple pools in PHP-FPM

Tags: php, nginx, load-balance

When reading the article on the link below, I had some doubts, I will explain my scenario and talk about my doubt.

https://dzone.com/articles/upstream-php-fpm-for-better-performance-1

I currently have a **32 GB** memory server, of which I left **20 GB** for PHP-FPM. I have a **www.conf** file, and I am using the **"ondemand"** method, the average consumption of my PHP-FPM pools is **29 MB**, so my **pm.max_children** is equal to **690**, my **pm.process_idle_timeout** is **15s**, and my **pm.max_requests** is equal to **1000**.

Is it worth it to create another **www2.conf**, calculate **10 GB** of memory for each one, and do the **"load balance"** of the requests that are entering using the upstream of nginx? Can this increase the performance and redundancy of my sites?

Comment: I can't directly answer your question and I'm not a PHP expert, but I suspect trying to load balancer across pools isn't going to help much. I only use different pools when I need different settings for a particular application or to keep things separated for security.

Comment: I'm finishing doing the tests here, and I really saw no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked article is from year 2016 and seems to be referring to PHP5.

PHP has taken big steps forward since that and most likely the article is invalid for current PHP versions.

I personally doubt that any such tuning would be beneficial.

However, I don't have any real-world experience on such a setup. I recommend you to test both setups with your workload and see if there is any benefit.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a legacy system that still uses PHP5, but I will test both configurations, if I don't see any gains, I leave it as it is currently, with a pool.